# Azure Web App didn't run (NodeJS) due to 'bcript' middleware

Tags: node.js, azure, express

> I'm setting up a new web app with Azure. Everything went find until I uploaded code from my Github, and the Website show this error : https://linuxserver.azurewebsites.net/
>
> This is the log: 
>   2019-04-17T05:40:54.659490887Z Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
>
> Here is my code on Github https://github.com/phongluudn1997/express-testing

This is for a new Linux server on Azure, running NoSQL using MLAB, Nodejs, Express

Comment: Did you run the command npm install in the directory where you have code in your azure linux server ?

Comment: How can I open a terminal in Web App?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clone your GitHub repo to run it on my local, then I found there are two problem.

1. The code `const define = require('../../lib/define');` in `routes\productAPI.js` can not works, because there is not a module `../../lib/define`, the error information below.

   ```
   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
       throw err;
       ^

   Error: Cannot find module '../../lib/define'
   ```
2. Considering for resource security, please never commit any code include a real resource connection string to a public repo.

---

Update:

There are two packages [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) and [`bcrypt.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) for hashing passwords, which be added into your `package.json` file. They are compatible in APIs, but `bcrypt` requires `node-gyp` with `GlibC` to compile while installing on Linux, `bcrypt.js` is a pure Javascript implement slower about 30% than `bcrypt`.

According to the above and the `node_modules` directory in your repo, I think your issue about `Cannot find module 'bcrypt'` was caused by these reason below.

1. There is not `bcryptjs` package in your `node_modules` when you only write [`var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');`](https://github.com/phongluudn1997/express-testing/blob/a72d67ff573c54744464c5067280a043ea08473f/routes/userAPI.js#L9) code in your project without using `bcrypt`.
2. The `bcrypt` package installation requires C/C++ compiler with GlibC only, but it may not be in your Azure Linux so that break the npm installation progress.

I suggest that you can try to remove the dependency `bcrypt` to fix the issue, because it seems that you did not use it in your project.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the second reason is the point of the problem, I created a Virtual Machine then use terminal to install the brypt pakage on VM and it worked, but how can I install brypt package in Web App?

Comment: @HuỳnhPhongLưu If using an image based on Alpine Linux, you need to follow the section [`Enable SSH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh) of the offical tutorial `Configure a custom Linux container for Azure App Service` to add `build-base` first before to run `npm install`.